# Nexus 7 tablet not recognized by adb

Tags: android, adb

I am having some strange behavior with the android sdk and my tablet. I am attempting to get my tablet recognized with:

```
adb devices -l
```

command.

Each time I plug the tablet in, a window on my computer pops up for a brief moment asking me recognizing the tablet as a camera and asking me what application do I want to open it with. Then it disappears before I click anything. On the tablet, it will say "allow usb debugging from such and such computer?". Some times that will disappear before I can click it. Other times I click it, but adb devices -l still does not recognize it. Then I check dmesg:

```
[ 3398.180553] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 45 using ehci_hcd
[ 3398.321392] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4e44
[ 3398.321404] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[ 3398.321411] usb 1-1: Product: Nexus 7
[ 3398.321416] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: asus
[ 3404.230444] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 45
```

I am using Linux Mint 14. I've not had a problem until recently.

Here is a list of steps I've taken to troubleshoot the problem:

1. Reboot my computer choosing different kernel versions
2. Restarting adb with adb kill-server and adb start-server
3. Plugging the tablets cable into 4 other usb ports
4. Rebooting the tablet
5. Double checking that usb debugging is still enabled (yes, it is)
6. lsusb (Should show Google Inc., but it is not)
7. I have the latest sdk and all is up to date
8. Googling, but I only found basic troubleshooting steps that I had already taken
9. More steps

I am unsure what else to do. But this loss in time of productivity is costing me. I am almost finished with my first app for a company and need to complete it, so I can sell them the product.

Answer (score 5):

You can try with these steps:

1. stop the server with: 
   adb kill-server.
2. Go to ~/.android/ and if doesn't exist create the file: adb_usb.ini
3. Add a line with the value: 0x18d1 (the vendorId of your device).
4. Save and close the file.

Try again. For me it worked (i'm using a 100 euros tablet...) 
Finally if you still have problems you can create an udev rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules, like the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM =="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE ="0666", GROUP ="plugdev"
```

And make sure that your user is in plugdev group.
Hope this help.

Comment: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules works. Note that it needs SUBSYSTEM (UBSYSTEM is missing the 'S')

Comment: ops... fixed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A friend gave me a new cable. Now my tablet shows with `adb devices -l`, `lsusb`, `dmesg` with no errors, and works from Eclipse Android SDK Bundle.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the permissions of the block device? Try starting the adb server as root.

Answer (score -2):

Do you have the right driver installed on your computer?

Even if the tablet is recognized, this doesn't necessarily mean the driver is installed.

You can find drivers for the Nexus 7 here: http://www.asus.com/Tablets_Mobile/Nexus_7/#support_Download_32

Comment: Hey is using Linux, so no need to install drivers.

Comment: Found this thread on connecting a Nexus 7 to Linux that might be helpsul: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=112342&f=49

Comment: Should work with no setup necessary, on latest Linux, ADB and a good usb cable.